# handleSubmit functional is not working in functional component of React

Tags: reactjs, react-functional-component

I am trying to convert class component of todo app into functional component. Everything goes well, but when I submit the form, the blank screen appears. I think there is some issue in handleSubmit function. Please help.

```
import React, {useState} from "react";

export const TodoFunc = (props: Props) => {

  const [items, setItems] = useState([])
  const [text, setText] = useState('')

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setText(e.target.value)
  }

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    if (text.length === 0) {
      return;
    }
    const newItems = {text: {text}, id: Date.now()}
    setItems(() => (items.concat(newItems)))
    setText('')
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h3>TODO</h3>
      <TodoList items = {items} />
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <label htmlFor="new-todo">
          What do you want to do?
        </label>
        <input type="text"
               id='new-todo'
               onChange={handleChange}
               value={text}
        />
        <button>
          Add #{items.length + 1}
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

const TodoList = (props) => {
  return (
    <ul>
      {props.items.map(item => <li key={item.id}>{item.text}</li>)}
    </ul>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem lies in the below line:

```
const newItems = {text: {text}, id: Date.now()}
```

Here you are assigning an object to the text key and not just the value of the variable text.

And this is why when you loop over them in your **TodoList** component you are not able to display any of them.

Comment: Glad to know that I could help! :)